# Read the users phonenumber in a browser

Tags: android, iphone, email, text, message

I've made a mobile page where the visitors of my site can leave their phonenumber, wich is send to me by mail so I can act on that; so far no problem.
My experience is, that visitors often don't bother to type their number or do not know their number.

Is it possible to read the device's phonenumber and put it in a textbox, so all the visitor has to do, is to press "call me" and the number is send to me by mail?

An alternative could be, to send a pre-defined message (defined in the internet page on my site) as a text message from/via the browser of the visitor via his text app.

Can anyone put me on the right track?
btw I live in the Netherlands.

Comment: If this were possible, would anyone use their phone to browse the web? Don't think so. Also, a phone may have multiple phone numbers (dual-SIM).

Comment: Why not? it never leaves the phone without an ok of the owner. Besides that, there are apps that do worse without even asking and are downloaded by the thousands. Dual sims are a seperate, but very small, problem in this case.

Comment: did you find any way?

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know, there's no way for you to get the devices phone number from the web browser.

Comment: pity, on a pc you can get al sorts of local information and show it in your browser. This information is only showed to you, the user of that specific pc. I hoped/thought it could be done on a phone too.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can read a phone number through the browser. However, you *can* make it easier for users to enter there phone number by using `<input type="tel">` which makes the keyboard look like this on devices:

[image: iPhone Keypad]

If you have the user choose their carrier (in a `<select>` box), you can easily use email to send a text message to their device:

- AT&T: **number**@txt.att.net
- Verizon: **number**@vtext.com

[etc.](http://hacknmod.com/hack/email-to-text-messages-for-att-verizon-t-mobile-sprint-virgin-more/). I do not know the carriers in the Netherlands, but it should function pretty much the same.

Comment: thnx! As we say in Dutch: "alle beetjes helpen" ("even small things help")